# LSZ theorem for trivial scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory

The $1\to1$ scattering amplitude is trivial and is given by (take massless scalars for simplicity)
$$
\tag{1}
\langle O(\vec{p}) O^\dagger(\vec{p}\,')\rangle  =  (2 | \vec{p}\,|) (2\pi)^{D-1} \delta^{(D-1)}(\vec{p} - \vec{p}\,') .
$$
On the other hand, a general $m\to n$ scattering amplitude is given via the LSZ Theorem as
\begin{align}
&\langle O_1 (\vec{p}_1) \cdots O_n(\vec{p}_n) O^\dagger_{n+1}(\vec{p}_{n+1} )  \cdots O^\dagger_{n+m}(\vec{p}_{n+m} ) \rangle \\
&\qquad \qquad \qquad =  \prod_{k=1}^{n+m} i \lim_{p_i^0 \to | \vec{p}_i|} (p_k^2 - i \varepsilon) G( p_1 , \cdots , p_n ; - p_{n+1} , \cdots , - p_{n+m} ) .
\end{align}
where $G$ is the Fourier transform of a time-ordered correlation function.

Let us apply the LSZ theorem to the $1\to 1$ scattering problem ($m=n=1$). In this case,
$$
G( p , - p' ) = \frac{-i}{p^2-i\varepsilon}(2\pi)^D \delta^{(D)}(p-p')
$$
We then find
\begin{align}
\langle O(\vec{p}) O^\dagger(\vec{p}\,')\rangle &= \lim_{p^0 \to | \vec{p}|} \lim_{p'^0 \to | \vec{p}\,'|} ( p^2 - i \varepsilon) ( p'^2 - i \varepsilon ) \left( \frac{1}{p^2-i\varepsilon} (2\pi)^D  \delta^{(D)}(p-p') \right)  \\
&= (2\pi)^{D-1} \delta^{(D-1)}( \vec{p}-\vec{p}\,')   \lim_{p^0 \to | \vec{p}|}  ( p^2 - i \varepsilon) 2\pi \delta ( p^0 - |\vec{p}\,| )  \\
\end{align}
Comparing this to the expected result (1), we find that we must have
$$
\tag{2}
 \lim_{p^0 \to | \vec{p}|}  ( p^2 - i \varepsilon) 2\pi \delta ( p^0 - |\vec{p}\,| )  = 2 |\vec{p}\,| . 
$$
How do I show that this? It seems entirely incorrect as the limit on the LHS seems to naively give 0. But perhaps there is a way to regulate the Dirac delta function and prove this.

PS - I should add that I have not been super careful about $\pm$ signs and possibly factors of 2 or $\pi$. As long as we can show that (2) is correct up to a normalization, I'm happy. I can figure out the exact factors later.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194986/84967